# how to invisible samba folder from unwanted users?

Tags: centos, samba

How to hidden samba shared folders from unwanted users.The folder should be visible for that particular user.How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to protect a shared folder, the simpler approach is to use the "valid users" smb.conf directive. In this manner, only the listed users will be granted access to the share. Please note that is a share-level permission. For file/directory-level permissions, you had to map Unix permission bits or use POSIX ACLs. Anyway, samba defaults parameters are quite reasonable.

See more [here](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch09.html)

Comment: Yes you are correct.But why the other folders are showing with sharing.i just want to restrict the rest of the folders.How to do it?

Comment: I did not understand what you mean. You want to deny _even_ share visibility while enumerating? Can you expand your question with more information?

Comment: Consider i have A ,B, C folders and i have users like user1 and user2. i want to assign folder A and B with user1 and C with User 2. If i login by user1 it should shows A and B only not Folder C. and If i login by user2 it should shows C only not A,B.I ask this only.Please help me

Comment: I think you are confusing _shares_ with _folders_. **Shares** are what you see when doing `\\servername`, while **folders** are (obviously) directories inside shares. If you have a single share with multiples directories that must be user-private, you had to understand how Samba and Linux/ACLs permissions works. If you don't want to do that, and if you have only _few_ directories to share, you can create a share for each directory and then configure the "valid user" directive _for each share_ as needed. Anyway, please read Samba documentation.